Conformal equivalent to Schwarzschild metric
Consider Schwarzschild spacetime in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates $(v,r,\theta,\phi)$
$$g \enspace = \enspace -f(r) \, dv^2 + 2 \, dv \, dr + r^2 \, d\Omega^2 \quad , \qquad f(r) = 1 - \frac{2m}{r}$$
with $d\Omega^2$ being the metric on the unit sphere. Its determinant is
$$\det g \enspace = \enspace - r^4 \sin^2 \theta$$
The determinant obviously diverge when taking the limit $r \rightarrow \infty$. Now, consider instead the conformally equivalent metric
$$\tilde{g} \enspace = \enspace \frac{1}{r} \, g$$
Its determinant is
$$\det \tilde{g} \enspace = \enspace - \sin^2 \theta$$
The determinant is well-defined at the limit $r \rightarrow \infty$, and so one could assume that the metric is non-degenerate there.$^{1)}$ The metrics coefficients, however, read
$$\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \tilde{g} \enspace = \enspace - \underbrace{\frac{f(r)}{r}}_{\rightarrow 0} \, dv^2 + \underbrace{\frac{2}{r}}_{\rightarrow 0} \, dv \, dr + r \, d\Omega^2$$
suggesting that the metric is degenerate there. Which of both is now true?

$^{1)}$ Does this therefore describe a new/an extended spacetime in which the "boundary" at spatial infinity is included?

You have a misconception. Neither metric is degenerate.
$det g$ should be $0$ somewhere in order for a metric to be degenerate. See here
With your definition even any innocent looking 2D polar metric $g=dr^2+r^2 d\theta^2$ would be a degenerate of the worst kind.
So there is nothing wrong with the conformal metric you propose

Hm, but how is that possible if the metric components vanish. If one represents the metric as a matrix, then the first 2x2 block is zero, the determinant should vanish then, shouldn‘t it?
